# Stack around the variable Opencv & C++

Tags: c++, opencv, stack

I'm working in a project with particle filter. This is a snippet of my code. When the program is executing, when leave this function VS2013 tell me a error: "**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'idx' was corrupted**."
Do you want any idea what is the problem??

Thanks you!

PS: additional info. If I execute the program in release mode it problem disappear...

```
void Particles::mergeClusters(cv::Mat image) {

    cv::Mat ids_new(0, 0, CV_32SC1);
    cv::Mat means_new(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
    vector<cv::Mat> covs_new(0);
    cv::Mat weights_new(0, 0, CV_64FC1);

    cv::Mat ids(0, 0, CV_32SC1);
    cv::Mat means(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
    vector<cv::Mat> covs(0);
    cv::Mat weights(0, 0, CV_64FC1);

    // temporary objects used to store non-chosen elements
    // this is the set I in the paper of Vo (Table II)
    clusters.ids.copyTo(ids);
    clusters.means.copyTo(means);
    clusters.covs.swap(covs);
    clusters.weights.copyTo(weights);

    int l = 0;
    while (!means.empty()) {

        cv::Mat means_t(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
        cv::Mat weights_t(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
        vector<cv::Mat> covs_t(0);

        int idx = 0;
        cv::minMaxIdx(weights, NULL, NULL, NULL, &idx);

        cv::Mat m_t(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
        cv::Mat w_t(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
        vector<cv::Mat> c_t(0);

        vector<int> L(0);

        for (int j=0; j<means.rows; j++) {
            cv::Mat u = (means.row(j)-means.row(idx)) * covs[j].inv() * (means.row(j)-means.row(idx)).t();
            if (u.at<double>(0) <= param.U) {
                m_t.push_back(means.row(j));
                w_t.push_back(weights.row(j));
                c_t.push_back(covs[j]);
                L.push_back(j);
            }
            else {
                means_t.push_back(means.row(j));
                weights_t.push_back(weights.row(j));
                covs_t.push_back(covs[j]);
            }
        }

        // Weight
        double W = sum(w_t)[0];
        // Mean
        cv::Mat M(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
        cv::repeat(w_t, 1, m_t.cols, M);
        cv::multiply(M, m_t, M);
        cv::reduce(M, M, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM);
        cv::divide(M, W, M);
        // Covariance
        cv::Mat C(0, 0, CV_64FC1);
        C = cv::Mat::zeros(covs[0].rows, covs[0].cols, CV_64FC1);
        for (int k=0; k<m_t.rows; k++) {
            C = C + w_t.at<double>(k) * (covs[k] + ((M-m_t.row(k)).t() * (M-m_t.row(k))) );
        }
        cv::divide(C, W, C);

        ids_new.push_back(idx);
        means_new.push_back(M);
        covs_new.push_back(C);
        weights_new.push_back(W);

        l++;

        // update I
        means.release();
        weights.release();
        covs.clear();

        means_t.copyTo(means);
        weights_t.copyTo(weights);
        covs_t.swap(covs);

        means_t.release();
        weights_t.release();
        covs_t.clear();
    }

    ids_new.copyTo(clusters.ids);
    means_new.copyTo(clusters.means);
    weights_new.copyTo(clusters.weights);
    covs_new.swap(clusters.covs);
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting memory or accessing an array/vector out of bounds.  Debug your program to determine where this is occurring.

Comment: You seem to release means,weights & covs and then try to copy data to them.  Release removes the memory of the matrix, Do you want to call [Mat::Empty()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-empty) instead?

Comment: The warning disappears in release mode because no checks for memory corruption are made in release mode.

Comment: `PS: additional info. If I execute the program in release mode it problem disappear...`  The problems are still there.  Be lucky that the debug mode is telling you that there are problems.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answers!!
The error appear when the program finish this function... Then the problem could is in everywhere in THIS function, no?
This code (complete code) is working properly in a Mac... I don't understand why it fail in Windows (VS2013)...
Thanks you!!

Comment: @Ricardo - The code is probably *not* working properly on the Mac.  Again, just because you don't see any issue doesn't mean there isn't one.  I can tell you this -- once you fix the problem with the Windows version, you better pull the Mac version and fix it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem.

I needed declare dinamically the int:

```
int *idx = nullptr;  // new pointer declared
idx = new int();    // memory dynamically allocated
```

Now it's working propertly!